# generalised procrustes analysis of sensory descriptive data

Tags: r, spss

I want to preform a GPA on sensory descriptive data - QDA data to examine panel consensus. I don't have XLSTAT and would like to do this in R or even SPSS if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FactoMineR` package, it has a function
for Generalised Procrustes Analysis (GPA) (https://rdrr.io/cran/FactoMineR/man/gpa.html).

More documentation on the package available here (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/FactoMineR.pdf), just search in the document GPA and you will find it.